# What does "that" indicate here?

Tags: meaning

People sometimes don't recognize talent when see it . Their vision is clouded by the first impression we give and **that** can lose us the job we want

What does **that** refer to?
first impression OR the whole preceding sentence?

Comment: You can't tell for sure from the syntax, but I'd say this structure is more often used to refer to the whole clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, **that** is a pronoun that refers to something that you have just mentioned. It could refer to "first impression" or to the idea expressed by the first half of the sentence, ie "Their vision is clouded by the first impression we give". Both make sense: both the idea and the first impression could be described as losing you the job.